# Cannot find the coordinates of the mouse

Tags: java

I'm very new to code, and am currently in the middle of making my first project, (just a simple game)  and here is a snapshot of some of the code. The up. down, left and right buttons work just fine, but the line 'mouse = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY(), -25);' does not seem to find the co-ordinates of the mouse despite having put in 'public Point mouse;'. Any suggestions?

```
public Rectangle character;

public int charW = 24;
public int charH = 36;

public boolean right = false;
public boolean left = false;
public boolean up = false;
public boolean down = false;
public boolean mouseActive = false;

/**
 *
 */
public Point mouse;

public Keying(Display f, Images i){
    character = new Rectangle(180, 180, charW, charH); 

    f.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                mouseActive = false;
                right = true;
                character.x += 1;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                mouseActive = false;
                left = true;
                character.x -= 1;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                mouseActive = false;
                up = true;
                character.y -= 1;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                mouseActive = false;
                down = true;
                character.y += 1;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_M){
                mouseActive = true;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D){
                right = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A){
                left = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W){
                up = false;
            }
            if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S){
                down = false;
            }
        }
    });

    f.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {

        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
            mouse = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY(), -25);
            if(mouseActive){
                character.x = mouse.x;
                character.y = mouse.y;
            }
            repaint();
        }           
    });
}    

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.fillRect(character.x, character.y, character.width, character.height);

    if(right){
        character.x += 1;
    }
    if(left){
        character.x -= 1;
    }
    if(up){
        character.y -= 1;
    }
    if(down){
        character.y += 1;
    }
    repaint();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `MouseEvent` object has a method called `getPoint()`. This will allow you to get the exact `Point` instead of having to create a new one with the X and Y values.

So, try changing the line:

`mouse = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY(), -25);`

to the following:

`mouse = e.getPoint();`

All of this information is available in the JavaDoc for `MouseEvent` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html)

Comment: I just managed to do it by myself anyway, a little bit differently to how you have done it but works just as good, thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries! Good luck with your project :)

Comment: Thankyou! It's all going well so far

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by myself, but if anyone is wondering what I did to do it this is the lines of code I used -

```
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){
            int mouseX = e.getX();
            int mouseY = e.getY();
            mouse = new Point(mouseX, mouseY);
```